# show all the commits on a specific bookmark in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

When I run `hg log -r remote/project` I get the last commit on that bookmark.

How can I get a full list of commits from the head of that bookmark?

Answer (score 1):

This is not (easily) possible in general. You can approximate it with `hg incoming` from an empty repository, but `hg incoming` actually does a complete pull of the difference and throws the contents away; it does not scale for large repositories. Any solutions that are both practical and general involve ssh-ing into the remote machine or setting up a separate server process on the remote machine.

An intermediate approach uses `hg incoming --bundle FILE -T ''` (the `-T ''` part is to suppress normal output). This will store the difference between your local version in an overlay repository called `FILE`; you can then use `hg log -R FILE` to perform normal log commands on the overlay repository (and you can also pull from it, as though it were a snapshot of the original remote). This still relies on you having a significant portion of the repository on your local machine, or it will result in a full download of the remote repository.